# Using scrapy to extract XHR request?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape social like counts that are being generated with javascript. I am able to scrape the desired data if I absolutely reference the XHR url. But the site I am trying to scrape dynamically generates these XMLHttpRequests with query string parameters that I do not know how to extract.

For example, you can see that using the m, p, i, and g parameters unique to each page are used to construct the request url.

[image: Query String Parameters]

Here is the assembled url:

http://aeon.co/magazine/social/social.php?url=http://aeon.co/magazine/technology/the-elon-musk-interview-on-mars/&m=1385983411&p=1412056831&i=25829&g=http://aeon.co/magazine/?p=25829

..which returns this JSON:

```
{"twitter":13325,"facebook":23481,"googleplusone":964,"disqus":272}
```

Using the following script, I am able to extract desired data (in this case twitter count) from the request url i just mentioned but only for that specific page.

```
import scrapy

from aeon.items import AeonItem
import json
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class AeonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "aeon"
    allowed_domains = ["aeon.co"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://aeon.co/magazine/technology"
]

def parse(self, response):
    items = []
    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="latestPosts"]/div/div/div'):
        item = AeonItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('./a/p[1]/text()').extract()
        item['primary_url'] = sel.xpath('./a/@href').extract() 
        item['word_count'] = sel.xpath('./a/div/span[2]/text()').extract()      

        for each in item['primary_url']:
            yield Request(http://aeon.co/magazine/social/social.php?url=http://aeon.co/magazine/technology/the-elon-musk-interview-on-mars/&m=1385983411&p=1412056831&i=25829&g=http://aeon.co/magazine/?p=25829, callback=self.parse_XHR_data,meta={'item':item})                   


def XHR_data(self, response):
    jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    item = response.meta['item']
    item["tw_count"] = jsonresponse["twitter"]  
    yield item
```

so my question is, how can I extract the m,p,i and g url query parameters so that I can dynamically simulate the request url? (rather than absolutely referencing it as shown above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This how you can extract your url:

```
import urlparse
url = 'http://aeon.co/magazine/social/social.php?url=http://aeon.co/magazine/technology/the-elon-musk-interview-on-mars/&m=1385983411&p=1412056831&i=25829&g=http://aeon.co/magazine/?p=25829'

parsed_url = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(url).query)

for p in parsed_url:
    print p + '=' + parsed_url[p][0]
```

and output:

```
>> python test.py
url=http://aeon.co/magazine/technology/the-elon-musk-interview-on-mars/
p=1412056831
m=1385983411
i=25829
g=http://aeon.co/magazine/?p=25829
```

Comment: for getting the `url` you need to do, `url=response.url` in `def parse(self, response):`

Comment: This answers part of my question, but I am still confused. How am I able to fetch the relative XHR to be stored as the variable 'url' rather than use an absolute url as you have shown?

Comment: do you mean how to make your new url and send it to `yield Request(...`. right?

Comment: before answering to your question, how did you came up with this url (http://aeon.co/magazine/social/social.php?url=http://aeon.co/magazine/technology/the-elon-musk-interview-on-mars/&m=1385983411&p=1412056831&i=25829&g=http://aeon.co/magazine/?p=25829)

Comment: I know how to send the url to yield request. Where I am having trouble is getting the unique XHR URL that is called on each individual page on http://aeon.co/magazine/technology/ (I have stored the parent urls in ['primary_url']). I'm trying to create a list of all the associated XHR urls that have the form:  'http://aeon.co/magazine/social/social.php?url=http://aeon.co/magazine/technology/the-elon-musk-interview-on-mars/&m=1385983411&p=1412056831&i=25829&g=http://aeon.co/magazine/?p=25829'.

Comment: I found it using the browser developer tool. I am trying get all urls of that structure on each of the pages I am iterating through in ['primary_url']

Comment: the url can be seen on the image I attached in the original post

Comment: Inside one of the `<script>` tags you have all of the information that you need (url, m, i, p). search for `//Socials` and you can find a `$.ajax` call that load the parameters. extract these data and this is all you want

Comment: ..wow..I feel dumb, that was way easier than I thought. For some reason I thought those requests were happening outside of the DOM. Anyway, what you said worked and I am back on track. I appreciate the help, thank you!