# Scrapy get all external Links of URL

Tags: hyperlink, scrapy, external

i use scrapy to spider an entire website (allow_domains = mydomain.com). Now i want to get all external Links (to another Domains) from the current URL. How can i integrate this in my spider.py to get a list with all external URLs?

Comment: What do you mean by getting all external links? all <a> tags that are redirecting to another domain?

Comment: I just want all <a href="[external-url]">[sometext]</a> from the current URL that i process.

I use this Rule atm:

rules = (
  Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='get_domain_data', follow=True),
 )

Comment: What is the problem of using scrapy link extractor ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [Link Extractors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#link-extractors). This can be an example:

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class MyItem(Item):
    url= Field()


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'twitter.com'
    allowed_domains = ['my-domain.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.my-domain.com']

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_url', follow=False), )

    def parse_url(self, response):
        item = MyItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        return item
```

Comment: Ok, i use the SgmlLinkExtractor already. I thought there is another util with Scrapy to get external links very simple. Then i try it with the xpath()

Comment: There is always different ways. You can use xpath to get all `a/@href` from the page and analyze them by some libraries like `urlparse` to extract the domain and compare it with current domain. this can be an example(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998433/using-scrapy-to-extract-xhr-request/27000903#27000903)

Comment: There is a problem in my thinking. I only want href="x" with external target. (http://www.otherdomain.com). But, how can i check these with relative URLs, when there is no domain in the href attribute? Any idea?

Comment: You mean when the href attribute is something like `href="javascript:void()"` or `href="\cat\link1"`. Right?

Comment: Yes. I trie'd something like this, but it doesnt work well:

//a[( contains(@href,'http://') or contains(@href,'https://') ) and not(contains(@href,'" + self.domain +"') )]/@href

Comment: You can use a fully integrated browser like `selenium` also that can click on the links as well. Using selenium will cover the case of javascript and hrefs with no domain.